# Use clonezilla without booting from the clonezilla live cd?

Tags: backup, clonezilla

I have two hard drives, /dev/sda and /dev/sda. Predictably, I boot from sda. When I boot from the clonezilla live cd and go through the wizard to make a backup image, it tells me that I can use a command like "/opt/drbl/sbin/ocs-sr -option1 -option2 imagename sdb."

I'd like to backup sdb without booting from the clonezilla live cd, in ubuntu, without rebooting, using a script called from cron, like this:

```
umount /dev/sdb1
/opt/drbl/sbin/ocs-sr -option1 -option2 imagename sdb.
mount /dev/sdb1 /path/to/mountpoint
```

But where can I get /opt/drbl/sbin/ocs-sr? Could I boot from the livecd and just copy /opt to wherever I want it? Wouldn't that skip any dependencies that I might not know about? Or is there somewhere that I could just download those files (everything I've found on the clonezilla site are iso's).

This isn't really ubuntu-specific, so apologies if this is the wrong place to ask. But I saw a bunch of other clonezilla questions here.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone on the clonezilla forum told me what I needed:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/clonezilla/forums/forum/663168/topic/6559272

In the answer at the Clonezilla forum one recommendation was to just copy ocs-sr.

There is a [deb file](http://free.nchc.org.tw/drbl-core/pool/drbl/) which can be used for the installation. Just go through the [installation description](http://drbl.sourceforge.net/installation/).

Comment: I summarized the instructions from the forum here. This helps to get an answer when the forum is unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

To get a copy of the command you "would" have used, go all the way through the process and then at the end, hit go to command prompt, then cd into /tmp and there should be a file called ocs-FILENAMEYOUCHOSE. Nano it and copy its contents. That is the command. But you will have to change file name inside command or it will overwrite/fail trying to copy same file destination if it exists.